# Counter not working in array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, count

I'm practicing finding max and min values, but I want to keep track of how many instances of those values I have. The program does find the min and max values, but it doesn't give the number of times the value appears in the array, so my counter is not working. Can someone give me a hand please? Thanks!

```
    int[] values = {222,34,56,222,45,1,3,222,56,10,15,56,1,222,12,23,1,222};

    int minValue = values[0];
    int maxValue = values[0];
    int counterMinValue = 0;
    int counterMaxValue = 0;
    int i;


    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if (values[i] < minValue){
            minValue = values[i];
            counterMinValue++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(values[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = values[i];
            counterMaxValue++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("The min value of this array is%2d and is repeated%2d times(s)", minValue, counterMinValue);
    System.out.printf("\nThe max value of this array is %2d and is repeated %2d time(s)", maxValue, counterMaxValue);
```

Here is the output:

The min value of this array is 1 and is repeated 2 times(s)

The max value of this array is 222 and is repeated  0 time(s)

Comment: You are checking to see if the current value is strictly less than the current min (or greater than the max).  Hint: how many times will `222` be greater than `222`?

Comment: Yeah, I know! That's part of the problem, so I tried <= and >= but it didn't give me the right counter either. I am a beginner!

Comment: Actually it does work for greater than! But not for less than...

Comment: That's an artifact of how the largest number in the array is also the first number in the array. My point is not that your condition statement is incorrect, but that your logic is incorrect.  If you find a new "smallest" or "largest" number, you can't just keeping adding to the "number of things I've found" counter, since you're now counting the *wrong number*.

Comment: I know my logic is wrong in the program, but I don't know how to fix it, that's the help I'm looking for here...

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == minValue) {
        counterMinValue++;
    }
    else if (values[i] < minValue) {
        minValue = values[i];
        counterMinValue = 1;
    }

    if (values[i] == maxValue) {
        counterMaxValue++;
    }
    else if (values[i] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = values[i];
        counterMaxValue = 1;
    }
}
```

Basically the same for loop that you have, except it checks to see if the current value is equal to the `minValue`, if it is, add to the counter, otherwise if the value is lower then set `minValue` to the current value and reset the counter, then do the same for the max value. I placed this in one `for-loop` since there is no point in iterating through the same list twice (with bigger sets of data that would greatly impact performance). I'm defaulting the counter to 1 so that you count the current element in the array and not just every element equal to it after.

Likewise, you'll probably want:

```
int counterMinValue = 1;
int counterMaxValue = 1;
```

EDIT:
In the case of your example where the largest (could also be smallest) value is the first in the array it gets counted twice due to this section:

```
if (values[i] == maxValue) {
    counterMaxValue++;
}
```

To correct this  you can change the for loop to start at 1 (since you already set the min and max value to the first item in the array you don't need to compare it to itself: `for (i = 1; ...)` which I have corrected in my above code.

Comment: This does not work either. The output is: The min value of this array is 1 and is repeated 2 times(s)

Comment: This works.  I would just do it one loop also.  You should just show that code since its the best solution

Comment: Why setting the counter to 1, and not to zero? I know there will be at least one instance of the min value, but I'm just wondering if it does make a difference.

Comment: Ok I made that change. And you set it to 1 because you are also initializing array[0] as being the lowest and highest number. So since that is initialized you want to set the counter to 1 (being that first item).

Comment: Also this should work as long as you initialized your counters to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] values = {222,34,56,222,45,1,3,222,56,10,15,56,1,222,12,23,1,222};

    int minValue = values[0];
    int maxValue = values[0];
    int counterMinValue = 0;
    int counterMaxValue = 0;
    int i;


    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if (values[i] == minValue) {
            counterMinValue++;
        }
        else if (values[i] < minValue){
            minValue = values[i];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] > maxValue) {
            maxValue = values[i];

        } else if (values[i] == maxValue) {
            counterMaxValue++;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("The min value of this array is%2d and is repeated%2d times(s)", minValue, counterMinValue);
    System.out.printf("\nThe max value of this array is %2d and is repeated %2d time(s)", maxValue, counterMaxValue);
}
```

I got these results:

```
The min value of this array is 1 and is repeated 3 times(s)
The max value of this array is 222 and is repeated  5 time(s)
```

Comment: This isn't an optimal solution. It will work but why iterate through the same list 4 times? By doing that you are significantly increasing the time complexity of the program

Comment: What would be an optimal solution for you? When I run your solution, the counter does not work either like mine...